# Significance of Palliyarai Pooja

Tags: temple, rituals

I have been to Shiva Temples and attended the Palliyarai Pooja. Recently, in Tiruchendur Murugan Temple also, i attended. What is the significance of Palliyarai Pooja?

Comment: Procession and arati performed at night in shiva temples while The Lord is going for a devine rest.